# Dagger with an interface as parameter

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Dagger and I want to inject a object who has an interface as parameter.

This is the interface:

```
public interface SchedulersProvider {

    Scheduler io();

    Scheduler ui();
}
```

The object that I want to inject is the following:

```
public class RestManager {

    private final RestApi restService;
    private final SchedulersProvider schedulersProvider;

    public RestManager(@NonNull SchedulersProvider schedulersProvider,
                       @NonNull Retrofit retrofit) {

        this.schedulersProvider = schedulersProvider;

        restService = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
    }


    public Single<List<BreedDto>> getBreeds() {
        return restService.getBreeds()
                .map(BreedsListDto::getBreeds)
                .compose(new SingleWorkerTransformer<>(schedulersProvider));
    }


    public Completable performImportantOperation() {
        return restService.performImportantOperation()
                .compose(new CompletableWorkerTransformer(schedulersProvider));
    }

    public Single<BreedStatsDto> getStats(long id) {
        return restService.getStats(id)
                .compose(new SingleWorkerTransformer<>(schedulersProvider));
    }

}
```

Finally here is how I have the dagger module:

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RestManager providesRestManager(SchedulersProvider schedulersProvider,
                                    Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new RestManager(schedulersProvider, retrofit);
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit providesRetrofit(@Named("endpoint") String endpointUrl,
                              Interceptor loggingInterceptor) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(endpointUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    MainPresenter providesMainPresenter(RestManager restManager) {
        return new MainPresenter(restManager);
    }
}
```

This is giving me the following error `SchedulersProvider cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method`

I don't know how to make this work because is the first time I had to inject an object who has an interface.

Comment: Well, where is the implementation for `SchedulersProvider` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not injecting `SchedulersProvider` at all. You need to inject it with a method annotated either with `@Provides` or `@Binds`, specifying the interface implementation that you want to use. Note that you can only use `@Binds` with abstract methods (i.e., your module would have to be abstract as well). So, with `@Provides`:

```
@Provides
SchedulersProvider provideSchedulersProvider(SchedulersProviderImpl schedulerProviderImpl) {
  return schedulerProviderImpl;
}
```

And with `@Binds`:

```
@Binds
abstract SchedulersProvider bindSchedulerProvider(SchedulersProviderImpl schedulerProviderImpl);
```